# Rounding up values using np.ceil

Tags: numpy, rounding, ceil

Why does np.ceil give me different answers for what should equivalent expressions?

```
np.ceil(336)
Out[34]: 336.0

np.ceil(100*(2.85+0.43+.08))
Out[35]: 337.0
```

Comment: I think it is floating point error in multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

## Ceil

The ceil of the scalar number x is the smallest number i, that is larger or equal to x (i.e., i>=x).

The first expression 336 is having data type int.

Whereas on evaluating the next expression it is found that the **result is not 336** but **336.00000000000006** , due to preserving information nature of language , the expression is in  which resulted in the ceil being calculated as 337 and not 336.

If you cast the expression to int like this int(100*(2.85+0.43+0.08)) then you will get `np.ceil` 336.

Comment: why is 100*(2.85+0.43+.08) not precisely 336?

Comment: Because you are using float values.

Comment: if you cast the expression to int like this `int(100*(2.85+0.43+0.08))` then you will get np.ceil 336.

Comment: @SusanaRodriguez Please Accept answer if it helped you.